# In Swift dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier taking time to load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am using Tableview in my Swift project. I made a custom cell and displaying custom cell with below method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedQuestionCell") as! FeedFirstTableViewCell
```

My Problem is when application load cell first time at that time it took 4-5 seconds to load cell means `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returning cell after 4-5 seconds.

I tried with making instance of cell on Appdel or any other class still same issue.

I tried with making XIB instead of making custom cell in storyboard same issue.

I tried with using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath method also but its also give me same result.

Can you please let me know if I am missing something or any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use normal cell with just some text on it? it looks like your cell is just really heavy

Comment: how do you know it's deque method that's taking time? Did you put breakpoints and debug that this takes time?

Comment: you hv the cell in viewcontroller storyboard or contructing it programtically?

Comment: @Lu_ yeah i tried with removing all auto layout  and removing controls from cell but it cause same issue? i did not removed declaration do you think that can cause issue?

Comment: @NikitaP yeah i placed breakpoints as well as placed log before assigning cell and after assigned cell it gives me delay in that.

Comment: @hariszaman 1 i was using with adding cell in storyboard inside tableview then i tried with making separate XIB for cell but in both case same issue

Comment: dont do any of that add just UITableViewCell not any custom one or show us everything you are doing to this cell

Comment: @Lu_ sure will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found issue.

Issue was i am assigning Custom Fonts in Storyboard and because of that in device it was taking time to load as in device those fonts are not installed.

We should assign the font programmatically instead of Storyboard will not cause this kind of issue.